# How to stop str_replace() replacing replacements?

Tags: php, numbers, str-replace

I have a little problem with `str_replace()` and numbers.

```
$jud='Briney Spears 12 2009';

$jud=str_replace(array('2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012'),'2013',$jud);

$jud=str_replace(array('0'),'',$jud);  
$jud=str_replace(array('1'),'By',$jud);  
$jud=str_replace(array('2'),'Gun',$jud);  
$jud=str_replace(array('3'),'Fast',$jud);

echo $jud ;
```

The result is

> Briney Spears ByGun GunByFast

I am looking for how the results of a '**Briney Spears ByGun 2013**' ?

Comment: The problem is the order of operations.  If you replace all years with 2013 first, then you individually replace occurrences of `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`, `2013` is going to be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the year with some placeholder. For example:

```
$jud = str_replace(array('2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012'), '%%YEAR%%', $jud);
```

Then replace numbers

```
$jud=str_replace(array('0'),'',$jud);
$jud=str_replace(array('1'),'By',$jud);
$jud=str_replace(array('2'),'Gun',$jud);
$jud=str_replace(array('3'),'Fast',$jud);
```

And then replace placeholder with the year:

```
$jud = str_replace('%%YEAR%%', 2013, $jud);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly. But you could do:

```
$jud='Briney Spears 12 2009';
$jud=str_replace(" 12 ", " ByGun ", $jud);
```

This would replace the 12 by ByGun without replacing 2012 for instance. If you need all months, you can put " 1 " to " 12 " in an array. Keep the space before and after.

```
$jud=str_replace(array(" 1 "," 2 "," 3 "," 4 "," 5 "," 6 "," 7 "," 8 "," 9 "," 10 "," 11 "," 12 "), " ByGun ", $jud);
```

Then, replace the year, just as you did.

Answer (score 1):

You can either change the order of replacement (replace year later) or use the array approach for `str_replace()`

```
$sentence    = 'Britney Spears 12 2009';
$toreplace   = array('2009', '2012');
$replacewith = array('2013', '2013');

echo str_replace($toreplace, $replacewith, $sentence); // Britney Spears 12 2013
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  If you simply replace the year later, the year substring will be mutated before the year replacement can be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Just for funsies :)

```
<?php
  $jud = 'Briney Spears 12 2009';
  $rep = array('', 'By', 'Gun', 'Fast');

  echo preg_replace(
    array_merge( array('/20(0[\d]|1[1-2])/'), 
      array_map( function($foo){
        return "/{$foo}(?![\d]{2,})(?!$)/";
      }, array_keys($rep))), 
        array_merge( array('2013'), $rep ), $jud, 1);
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/Y7A3WP)